# Trabajar con un documento que viene en una variable

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015

Trabajo con Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2015, C#

Tengo un xml que lo tengo en una ruta en disco para hacer pruebas y me funciono.
Lo que hago es serializo ese xml a clase para luego deserializarlo y obtener los datos.

```
var pathXml = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EsquemaXML");
        var pathFacturaXml = Path.Combine(pathXml, "Factura_001-100-000000016_1006.6_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.xml");

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(factura)); //Deserealizo el XML a clase
        var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(pathFacturaXml); 

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            _factura = (factura)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

Pero poniendo ese código en mi proyecto real el documento xml viene en una variable como un string y necesito hacer lo anterior.

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (factura)); //Deserealizo el XML a clase
                    //var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(documento); //Le agrego el docuento que viene como string.
                    var comprobante = new XmlDocument();
                    comprobante.LoadXml(documento + ".xml");
                    //var nombre = string.Concat("documento", ".xml");
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.ToByte(comprobante)))
                    {
                        _factura = (factura)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

En la variable documento tengo el xml como un string, me parece que tengo que ponerle un nombre y la extensión pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: no es LoadXml(documento) directamente?

Comment: Nesecito que tenga la extension.  xml porque voy a deserializarlo

Comment: me parece que estas confundiendo los tantos. Necesitas que sea un stream. Y en tu segundo caso, es un memoryStream, lo cual es correcto. Solo tenes que llenar ese stream con el string que vos queres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la variable `documento` tiene un xml como string no debes aplicar ninguna extension ni referencia a un archivos fisico, salvo que en realidad la variable tenga asignado el nombre del archivo al cual debes acceder.

Por lo tanto deberias usar

```
string documento = "<factura>...</factura>";
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(documento);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (factura));

_factura = (factura)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

La idea es que `documento` contiene los tags del `xml`

[Simple deserialization of XML to C# object](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11)

Comment: Gracias Leandro, fue mi solución.